# Looking for way to automate testing kshell app

Tags: shell, awk, automated-tests

I inherited a shell-script application that is a combination of kshell scripts, awk, and java programs.  I have written JUnit tests for the java pieces.

Is there a good way to do something similar for the kshell scripts and awk programs?

I have considered using JUnit and System.exec() to call the scripts, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found [shUnit2](http://code.google.com/p/shunit2/) and will try that.

Update with the results of trying out shUnit

shUnit works as expected.  Script files are written with test functions defined and then a call to shUnit.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
testFileCreated()
{
  TESTFILE=/tmp/testfile.txt
  # some code that creates the $TESTFILE
  assertTrue 'Test file missing' "[ -s '${TESTFILE}' ]"
}
# load shunit2
. /path/to/shUnit/shunit2-2.1.5/src/shell/shunit2
```

Result

```
Ran 1 test.

OK
```

The 'OK' would be replaced with 'FAILED' if the file did not exist.

Comment: I installed `shunit2` using `yum`. How can I tell where it is installed? Neither which nor locate can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/).  It was designed for automating interactive programs.  Of course  Expect was written on top of TCL, which is an abominable scripting language.  So there are interfaces for Python ([Pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/)) and perhaps other languages that are more programmer friendly.  But there is lots of documentation laying around for TCL/Expect that is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you may consider using a simple Makefile to run bash scripts with different parameters.

For example, write something like this:

```
cat >Makefile

test_all: test1 test2 test3

test1:
    script1 -parameter1 -parameter2

test2: $(addprefix test2file_, $TESTFILES)
test2file_%:
    script2 -filename $*

test3:
    grep|awk|gawk|sed....
```

By calling 'make test_all' you will execute all the scripts automatically, and the syntax is not so difficult to learn - you just have to define a rule name (test1, test_all...) and the commands associated with it.